# Phonegap export to Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, sdk, phonegap-cli

I have this working and for a long time was all cool, then at some point it stopped working without me having touched it. I see this error:

> `ERROR building one of the platforms: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Detected 'android' command at C:\Users\Tower\bin but no 'tools' directory found near.
>   Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include path to valid SDK directory.`

When I do `echo $ANDROID_HOME` I see:

> `C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools`

which is correct and I have the android sdk. When I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` it shows:

> `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin`

which is also correct. I have reinstalled both the Java JDK and the Android SDK. I am running this on Windows 10, X64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In variable `ANDROID_HOME` must be only path to the root directory of android-sdk i.e. `C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`.

In `JAVA_HOME` also must be only path to JDK root directory i.e. `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`.

This PATHs `C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools` must be in PATH System Environment Variable.

And this path to jdk bin directory `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin` must be in `PATH` Environment Variable.

#### Edit:

PATH should include `;` not `:`

Comment: Very same result, is there a way to check which paths are cordova checking? 
`echo $ANDROID_HOME
C:\Users\Tower\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
 echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
echo $PATH
xxx:/c/Users/Tower/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/c/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/Users/Tower/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/tools:xxx
`

Comment: is this normal that `;` turn into `:` on my terminal? if i check from system, there are `;`

Comment: strange, that was the problem, i open cmd and it's worked out, commonly i am using terminal from git.

Comment: include in answer that i must to check that echo PATH should include `;` not `:`